# Getting WMS server from GLOBELAND30 Landcover interactive map?

Tags: qgis, wms, land-cover

I am very interested to get [GLOBELAND30](http://www.globallandcover.com/GLC30Download/index.aspx) WMS server. To get it I've used some hacking:

1) I've inspected it with **Chrome Inspector** and did some actions (see below):

[image]

2) Got WMS server (see below)

[image]

3) Added the WMS url `http://218.244.250.80:8080/erdas-apollo/coverage/CGLC?LAYERS=cglc30_2010_0` to QGIS where it shows WMS layers but can't load the data.

[image]

Is there any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wouldn't be a valid WMS capabilities document - where as "http://218.244.250.80:8080/erdas-apollo/coverage/CGLC?service=wms&request=getCapabilities" is.

Since the GetCapabilities file refers to an internal machine name (`GLC-IS`) remember to check the ignore getMap/getTile in capabilities box.